# Сохранение файлов в определенную папку. Программа берет неправильный путь

Tags: python, файлы, path, save

Мне необходимо брать файлы из 'D:\Study\Progs\test\samples' и после обработки сохранять в 'D:\Study\Progs\test"вводимое значение"', но после строчки "name = os.path.abspath(file)" программа берет ложный путь "D:\Study\Progs\test\file.wav", а не "D:\Study\Progs\test\samples\file.wav", в чем может быть причина?

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


pa = "./"
save = pa+input()
os.mkdir(save)
for file in os.listdir("./samples"):
    if file.endswith(".wav"):
        print(file)
        name = os.path.abspath(file)
        ss = os.path.splitext(name)[0]+".png"
        print(name)
        audio = name
        x, sr = librosa.load(audio, mono=True, duration=5)
        save_path = os.path.join(save, ss)
        X = librosa.stft(x)
        Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
        plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
        librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr)
        plt.savefig(save_path)
```

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать путь к файлу, после создания новой папки, то есть прописать os.chdir('samples') после os.mkdir(save), тем самым перейти в новую папку. Иначе, вы проверяете с помощью listdir() в первом цикле путь старый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После всех вариантов, найденных в гугле, я пришел к следующей рабочей версии...

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path.cwd()
print("Vvedite directoriu dlya sohraneniya resultatov:")
sf = input()
save_folder = cwd / sf
print("Vvedite nazvanie directorii s primerami .wav failov:")
smpl = input()
sample_dir = cwd / smpl
os.mkdir(save_folder)

for file in sample_dir.glob("*.wav"):
    print(file)
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    outfile = os.path.splitext(base)[0] + ".png"
    print(f"->{outfile}")
    audio = file
    x, sr = librosa.load(audio, mono=True, duration=5)
    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, outfile)
    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr)
    plt.savefig(save_path)
```

Comment: Если используете pathlib, то и basename, splitext, join имеет смысл заменить на соответствующие аналоги из pathlib. К примеру, замена расширения в одну строку: `outfile = file.withsuffix(".png").name`. Путь сохранения: `save_path = save_folder / outfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


pa = "./"
save = pa+input()
os.mkdir(save)
samples = "./samples"
os.chdir(samples)
for file in os.listdir("./samples"):
    if file.endswith(".wav"):
        print(file)
        name = os.path.abspath(file)
        ss = os.path.splitext(name)[0]+".png"
        print(name)
        audio = name
        x, sr = librosa.load(audio, mono=True, duration=5)
        save_path = os.path.join(save, ss)
        X = librosa.stft(x)
        Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
        plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
        librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr)
        plt.savefig(save_path)
```